# Want browser specific links using css only

Tags: html, css

I want to show the links based on browser.
for ex: if the browser is chrome, i want to show the link with classname ".for-chrome" only and hide the other links.

I tried with the CSS, but it's working for chrome, but in firefox, it hides both the links.
Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/a7fxqmcw/

```css
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .for-chrome {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .for-firefox {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
```

```html
<p class="click-btn for-chrome"><a href="#for-chrome">For Chrome</a></p>
<p class="click-btn for-firefox"><a href="#for-firefox">For firefox</a></p>
```

Can someone help me find the alternate solution for this

Comment: I just tried in firefox and it works for me

Comment: I think we can use, navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Browser Name") in js for finding the browser and according to that we can show and hide the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use media queries like the following:

```css
.for-firefox {
  display: none !important;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .for-chrome {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .for-firefox {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
```

but note that this solution is only considering (firefox, not firefox) browser states, regardless of other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    // Is Opera
    let brow = document.querySelector('.show-opera')
    brow.classList.add('show')
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    // Is Chrome
    let brow = document.querySelector('.show-chrome')
    brow.classList.add("show")
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    // Is Safari
    let brow = document.querySelector('.show-safari')
    brow.classList.add('show')
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    // Is Firefox
    let brow = document.querySelector('.show-firefox')
    brow.classList.add('show')
  } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) //IF IE > 10
  {
    // Is IE
    let brow = document.querySelector('.show-ie')
    brow.classList.add('show')
  } else {
    // Not detected, may show all links
    document.querySelector('.hide-all').classList.add('show')
  }
}
myFunction()
```

```css
.hide-all {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<p class="click-btn hide-all show-chrome"><a href="#for-chrome">For Chrome</a></p>
<p class="click-btn hide-all show-firefox"><a href="#for-firefox">For firefox</a></p>
<p class="click-btn hide-all show-safari"><a href="#for-safari">For Safari</a></p>
<p class="click-btn hide-all show-opera"><a href="#for-opera">For Opera</a></p>

<p class="click-btn hide-all show-ie"><a href="#for-ie">For IE</a></p>
```